# Cannot import library file from ESP32 sdk library in "Eclipse C++ IDE for Arduino" project

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, eclipse

I have successfully installed "Eclipse C++ IDE for Arduino" and the Plugin works fine. Now I installed a custom board (ESP32) by adding package_index.json URL in windows>prefrences>C/C++>Arduino. The board installed and also work fine. 
The only problem I'm facing is that I'm unable to import platform SDKs and libraries.(e.g. #include "driver/adc.h") which are present in the path: G:\program\eclipse.arduinocdt\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.2\tools\sdk\include
I just want to import files just like in the Arduino IDE.

Eclispse version :
Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)
Build id: 20190314-1200

Thank You

Comment: what Eclipse Arduino plugin? Sloeber? you don't need to import them. they are part of the esp32 Arduino core

Comment: I'm using  Eclipse C++ IDE for Arduino, that is included in Eclipse CDT tools, when I import "driver/adc.h" i get build error. here is the link of the plugin: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-c-ide-arduino